# On what grounds can President Obama run for a third time?

Tags: united-states, election, election-requirements, presidential-term, barack-obama

Only one president, Franklin D. Roosevelt, has ever served more than two terms.

A while ago President Obama has announced that he will ***not*** run a third time and said:

> "even if the 22nd Amendment didn't exist, I'd still be out of the running."

- Is there a way around the 22nd amendment that limits presidents to two terms?
- Could he attempt to repeal the amendment?
- Also, even if he was successful at repealing the 22nd Amendment what other laws are in place to prevent him from running a third time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Attempts_at_repeal

Comment: Ronald Reagan was so popular that there was some discussion at the end of his presidency about repealing the 22nd Amendment so he could run again. He even stated an intent to campaign for it after he left office, but his Alzheimer's diagnosis prevented that from ever happening.

Comment: @JustinLardinois I'd like to see direct evidence of that claim.

Comment: @RonJohn http://www.nytimes.com/1987/11/29/us/reagan-wants-end-of-two-term-limit.html For what it's worth, this article quotes him as saying he wants the repeal for the benefit of future presidents, not himself.

Comment: Are you asking about only the 2016 election, or future elections as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [22nd amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) is the only law preventing him from running for a third term.

In theory, they could amend the constitution to allow him to run for a third term.  There are a couple problems though:

1. They probably wouldn't finish amending the constitution before election day.  It requires action by both the federal Congress and at least three-fourths of the state legislatures after that.  Note that passage to ratification took almost four years for the 22nd amendment.
2. Obama supporters do not currently control the state legislatures of enough states.  Nor enough votes in Congress (two-thirds of each house).

So while it is theoretically possible, it is not practical.

Obama is also not popular among armed citizens or the military, so it seems unlikely that he could successfully lead a rebellion.

Comment: I suspect he wouldn't want to continue being President, let alone starting an insurrection to stay in power.

Comment: Typically, a national leader, such as a President, that decides to stay in power by ignoring provisions in their own Constitution or by ignoring election laws tends to try to stay in power, and sets themselves up as a dictator. They often change or replace the Constitution or change the election laws so they legally stay in power forever. The only time when a rebellion results in democracy is when the rebellion comes from the people. Otherwise it usually winds up creating a dictatorship.

Comment: @ScottM.Stolz and even in that case more often than not it just replaces one dictatorship with another.

Comment: The 22nd Amendment is, by definition, not a law.

Comment: @DrunkCynic how do you figure? Article VI says that it is.

Comment: @jwenting Very true. If someone is willing to seize power, they usually don't like giving it back.

Comment: @DrunkCynic The Constitution is defined as the "highest law of the land" in the Constitution itself. People usually use terms like "constitutionally" and "constitution" instead of "legally" and "law" simply to emphasize the point that we are referring to the highest law of the land, and not an act of Congress or a state legislature. But technically, it's all "legal" and "law."

Comment: @ScottM.Stolz The Constitution is not defined as the highest law of the land. Rather, "This Constitution, and the *Laws of the United States* which shall be made in Pursuance thereof; and all Treaties made, or which shall be made, under the Authority of the United States, shall be the supreme Law of the Land." There is a legal distinction between Law of the Land and laws.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Notice the quote you mentioned actually says "This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States... shall be the supreme Law of the Land." The very Constitution states that the Constitution is "the supreme Law of the Land" because of the word "and" between "Constitution" and "the Laws of the United States." It grammatically says both are the supreme law of the land, if we want to get technical about it.

Comment: These comments gain an interesting new perspective in the light of the 2020 election.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Hm. Obama didn't want to start an insurrection to stay in power? That's crazy! He didn't tell his followers to march on the Capitol, and his followers didn't invade the Capitol waving Confederate flags? How silly of him!

Comment: @LieutenantZipp My comment was more to point out that I didn't think he wanted to be President. You can see just from physical changes the stress it caused him.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Yeah, no, I get that. I was just drawing a parallel to Obama's successor's actions while in the process of leaving office. I thought your comment was appropriate for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I believe his "even if there wasn't a 22nd Amendment" was not a statement that he would be otherwise ineligible, but, rather, would not be interested.

However, to more directly answer the question - since the 22nd Amendment does exist, there are and would be no legitimate no grounds for a third run for Barack Obama.